# Directory model not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, scrapy

I need to make a project which says:

> Crawl and Display
>
> Take this page - http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair
>
> Write a crawler using Scrapy, that will extract all the businesses listed there from pages 1 to 10. Store that data into MySQL. Create a schema that stores the following properties:
>
> Name of business,
> Address (multiple address possible),
> About,
> Photo (multiple photo possible),
> Phone number,
> Website URL
>
> It is very important that you really try and develop a good schema. This tests your RDBMS concepts, which is very necessary.
>
> Create an application using Django, which will allow a user to view the above data. Data editing NOT required. This application should look and work very much like the original Sun directory site.

But my models.py is giving problem. Here is the code for it:

```
from django.db import models


class Directory(models.Model):
    Bussiness_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Web_url = models.URLField(max_length=800)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Bussiness_name+" / "+self.adress_name+" / "+self.Description+" / "+self.Number+" / "+self.Web_url+" / "+self.Photo_name

class Adress:
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   adress_name =  models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Photos:
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   Photo_path =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Photo_name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

All models should models.Model subclass. This will work like a wheel:

```
class Adress(models.Model):
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   adress_name =  models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Photos(models.Model):
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   Photo_path =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Photo_name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Please elaborate 
i did not get you
the thing u wrote , I wrote that only
where is my mistake?